# Why JSESSIONID doesn't change after logging in when using a custom security filter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've noticed that **JSESSIONID** doesn't change after logging in when using a custom security
filter.

[image]

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .permitAll();
  }


  public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    CustomFilter customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    customFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return customFilter;
  }
```

Even if I put `sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession()` but when I remove the custom filter JESESSIONID does get refresed every time I log in and out.

Does anybody know why ? I would like to understand.

The custom filter has the same implementation of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

```
public class CustomFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
      throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
    } else {
      String username = this.obtainUsername(request);
      String password = this.obtainPassword(request);
      if (username == null) {
        username = "";
      }

      if (password == null) {
        password = "";
      }

      username = username.trim();
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
      this.setDetails(request, authRequest);
      return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
  }
  
}
```

I build the simple project fallowing this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the default `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is a `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy`.

By simply extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and creating a new instance, the custom filter will use a `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy`.

When Spring Security creates the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` from the form login configuration, it sets the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` to the strategy configured in `HttpSecurity`, defaulting to `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy`.

If you trace through the code, you can see how this happens.

When configuring `http.formLogin()` Spring Security creates a `FormLoginConfigurer` which extends `AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`.

The `FormLoginConfigurer` constructor creates a new instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Later, when the `configure` method is called on the `FormLoginConfigurer`, you will notice various properties are set on the filter, one of which is the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

```java
SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy = http
        .getSharedObject(SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
if (sessionAuthenticationStrategy != null) {
    this.authFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy);
}
```

If you look at the `SessionManagementConfigurer`, you will notice that the default strategy is `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy`.

The `SessionAuthenticationStrategy#onAuthentication` is later called in the `doFilter` method of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

That is why the filter configured by Spring Security will change the session ID after login, while a new instance of the filter, with no properties set, will not.

Comment: Thank you. @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana

Comment: Thanks @Eleftheria, In the code the AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer does sets few things on the filter (setAuthenticationManager, setRememberMeServices, setSecurityContextRepository, etc).
What is the best way to create our own AuthenticationFilter?

Comment: Doing this: `http.setSharedObject(SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class, new ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy());` does not help,